# Generics and inheritance with bounds

Tags: java, generics

In following code:

```
class BaseT {}

class Base<T extends BaseT> {}

class CLass1T extends BaseT {}

class Class1<T extends Class1T> extends Base<T> {}
```

I would like:

a) class `Class1` should inherit class `Base` and parameter in bounds should be passed to class Base (It is done in this code)

b) `Class1` should have parameter `Class1T` in their code, not `T`. Something like this:

```
class Class1<T> extends Base<Class1T> {}
```

c) `Class1` should be opened to inheritance. Example:

```
class CLass2T extends CLass1T {}

class Class2 extends CLass1<Class2T> {}
```

How to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: All your classes compile fine. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution. If I understand correctly your requirement "open for inheritance".

```
class Class1<T extends Class1T> extends Base<T> {}
```

Comment: I forgot about third condition. Now, you can answer.

Comment: Then problem with b condition occurs. When I create field in `Class1` of parameter T, then is type T, not Class1T.

Comment: It seems that your requirements are self-contradictory